# "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" using Spring boot 3.0.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, csrf

I am using Spring boot 3.0.5 along with Spring Security 6.
I am facing this issue when I am trying to call an endpoint to register an account into the application: **An expected CSRF token cannot be found**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
```

This is my security configuring class, note that I disabled csrf but I still get the above message.
Can you help me understanding what I've done wrong? Thank you!

I've tried to call a register account endpoint but faced the issue:**An expected CSRF token cannot be found**. I would have expected not to receive this message since I disabled csrf into security configuration class
[calling register endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3qUz.png)

Comment: Have you tried with simply `http.csrf().disable()`?

Comment: yes, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This config is not catching the requests to `/api/auth/**`:

```java
.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
```

Specifically configuring the endpoints to apply this configuration on will work, i.e.:

```java
.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
)
```

Demo: https://github.com/hugoalexandremf/spring-security-demo

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#use-new-security-matchers

Comment: done that but still getting same message

Comment: I put up a simple demo with this config (https://github.com/hugoalexandremf/spring-security-demo) - /auth/test is allowed. A simple HTTP GET to http://localhost:8080/auth/test will exemplify this use case scenario.

Comment: I can see your example is working but it seems like mine is still failing to work for some reason.

Comment: @AdrianValentin I'm facing that issue too when sending requests through the api gateway. Did you find a solution for that?